# using JScrollPane with JFrame, JPanel and GridLayout

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout (of JTextFields : 57*57) in a JPanel in a JFrame (resolution 800*800) and the result is really small and that's why I would like to have a JScrollPane (that would have a 800*800 resolution and the GridLayout resolution would be 3000*3000 for example).

I've tried many things but it was not working. Can someone please help me ?

Here is the concerned part of the code :

Thanks.

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(thumbnail.getHeight(), thumbnail.getWidth(),0,0);
            final_frame = new JFrame();
            final_frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));   

            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
            myPanel.setLayout(grid);

           //fill grid with colors and denomination
            for (int yy=0;yy<thumbnail.getHeight();yy++){
                for (int xx=0;xx<thumbnail.getWidth();xx++){
                    for (int kk=0;kk<colors.length;kk++){

                      if (thumbnail.getRGB(xx,yy)==colors[kk].getRGB()){
                          //System.out.println("Color : "+colors[kk]+" libel : H"+libel[kk]);
                          JTextField tf = new JTextField("H"+libel[kk]);
                          tf.setBackground(colors[kk]);
                          tf.setSize(10, 10); //do nothing ?
                          myPanel.add(tf);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            final_frame.add(myPanel);
            final_frame.pack();
            final_frame.setVisible(true);
            final_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            final_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: It's not working because nowhere in the code above do you use a JScrollPane

Comment: side note: If this were my project, I'd think strongly about using a JTable, yes one that is embedded in a JScrollPane

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the idea of the JTable, it works perfectly now ;)